# How to add a Journal to Visual SourceSafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am still using Microsoft Visual SourceSafe.

How can I add a journal to my projects?

By journal I mean a file, where all the changes in my projects will be logged to.

For example, when I check in a file named 'space_report.sql' in the journal it will be said
space_report.sql was checked in by "user name" at "the time when it happened".

I used to have this set up, can't remember how I did it.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you got an error message when trying to add the file? Can you post the screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click the folder or file. and select view history. 
if you view history of a folder, then you have the option to recurse to sub folder.

try it and let me know

[image]
[image]
[image]